# Sanitize Data Up to the Point Where Counts are Equal

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, statistics, jupyter-lab

We have performance metrics data with the given columns `['Timestamp','CID','API Elapsed','E2E Elapsed','Size (Byte)','Rows']`.

We are trying to translate this data in a Jupyter Notebook and so far it was trivial to get the normal distribution, histograms and etc. But here is a catch in our scenario; the idea was to connect, let's say, 200 clients to our service and then measure API & E2E latencies but from 1 to 200 clients, the login ramp-up takes time. Hence, we need to clean up the data before the point where 200 clients are connected.

Because, up to that point, the logins are still in progress and due to an internal publish queue, the elapsed times are pretty high. For example, consider this simplified table with 5 clients;

| Timestamp | CID | 'Elapsed' |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1622047594 | 1 | 50 |
| 1622047595 | 1 | 55 |
| 1622047595 | 2 | 72 |
| 1622047596 | 1 | 63 |
| 1622047596 | 1 | 40 |
| 1622047596 | 2 | 64 |
| 1622047596 | 3 | 99 |
| 1622047596 | 4 | 116 |
| **1622047597** | **1** | **50** |
| **1622047597** | **2** | **58** |
| **1622047597** | **2** | **50** |
| **1622047597** | **2** | **42** |
| **1622047597** | **3** | **62** |
| **1622047597** | **3** | **39** |
| **1622047597** | **4** | **57** |
| **1622047597** | **5** | **129** |
| 1622047598 | ... | ... |
| 1622047598 | ... | ... |

What we want to achieve is:

1. We want to separate the data into 2 parts; where the separation point is the data all clients appear in the same Timesamp the first time. I highlighted that in the table above. We cannot simply check the highest client CID since the CIDs might not be ordered, i.e. CID:5 may appear before CID:1.
2. What if instead of looking into the very same Timestamp to check Step-1 but we require to set a sensitivity like (+/-)5 pips?

The goal is understanding login latencies and the login process effect on the overall data latency by using the first part of the data and the overall latency after all logins are completed using the the second part of the data.

Thank you for your help in advance!

Comment: You could try just a linear search. You could also do a binary search which would be very fast to find the timestamp, and this would be very easy if once all customers were online, none signed out (or at least not for an extended period of time). How much data do you have?

Comment: More than 10M rows @Kraigolas but I couldn't get your answer, how exactly can I find the exact timestamp with or without sensitivity where all clients are connected?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just as a nice basic example assuming your data is sorted by timestamp:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict({"timestamp" : [1, 1, 2, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4], 
                             "y"         : [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]})

threshold = 3
last_timestamp = -1 # no timestamp in your actual data is ever -1
for stamp in df["timestamp"]:
    if stamp != last_timestamp:
        count = 0
        last_timestamp = stamp
    count += 1
    # count won't ever exceed threshold, but using >= just to show that we want > cases
    if count >= threshold:
        print(f"The first timestamp where all customers are online is {stamp}")
        result = stamp
        break
```

The result prints:

> The first timestamp where all customers are online is 4

Here:

- `threshold` is the total number of customers you have. It is where you will stop iterating because you have seen that all customers are online

and in this case, we are just walking through the data, row by row. We count all of the rows where the timestamp is the same, and if our count meets the threshold, we break. If you want a +/- of say 5 customers, you just have to lower the threshold by 5 as the + case is handled by this threshold (if you have more online than the threshold, it will still report that as the timestamp where all customers were online.

With only 10 million rows, this will be sufficiently fast for your purposes, running in 0.0005 seconds on my computer.

Now to actually split the data:

```
df_less = df[df["timestamp"] < result]
df_geq = df[df["timestamp"] >= result]
```

Where:

- `df_less` is before all customers are online
- `df_geq` is after that initial timestamp where all customers were online

Comment: TYVM @Kraigolas, I think this would do the job.